# Read the text in Image of table

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

What I'm trying to make is an app which requires user to click a photo of nutritional information on the back of food products.Currently I'm implementing this through tesseract library.I've been able to make the app to read text in images even in tables with large text and less data.But the problem is that nutritional information is given in text which is relatively small in size and given in form of table.
Solutions I've tried:

1. Ran the image through cam scanner than read the text but not enough accurate results.
2. Expanding the project https://github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr but again with not satisfactory results.
   My question:
   Is there any tweak or any tool or any method available so that I can convert image in form of table to text with text as small as given behind typical food products nutritional information.

Comment: See https://stacks.stanford.edu/file/druid:hg315sw1225/Grubert_Gao.pdf

Comment: Is this an ongoing project or is available online cause it looks great for my particular needs.

Comment: Hi,I used the same project and need to get the small text from the image.I am stuck here.The image may contain tables, spaces or image may contain bills like bank generated slips.I need to get the small text from bills.Please Help me ASAP.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hey, unfortunately the ocr technology is not yet advanced enough to meet your needs especially if its tables and in it small text you need to process.You can check the progress of the project given in the pdf link above the research is going on.